# How to find exe listening on port?

Tags: windows, networking, ports

I try with netstat -ab -p tcp -n and among the results get:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:47001          0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
Can not obtain ownership information
```

I am running as administrator and get that message. I also downloaded a utility to show network activity for exe's but nothing open is listening on port 47001 according to the utility.

How can I find out what is listening?

Comment: Did you try something like Wireshark?

Comment: @vvsraju  wireshark is notorious for (understandably) not showing you the EXE.  It's simply not mentioned in the packet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try `netstat -o` to get the process id (PID) and then use `tasklist |findstr <pid>` to see the process name and type. Task Manager also shows PID and process name.

You can combine your other switches with `-o` like so: `netstat -bona -p tcp`

Comment: I hadn't mentioned -b  because netstat with -b can be useful but some issues, A)it requires admin priv, and B)takes time to give a result.

Comment: `tasklist | find` is an issue(hence also not mentioned pre cees edit), because bizarrely for some reason, it doesn't always work. What does always work with filtering tasklist is tasklist >a then `type a |find` (or as some prefer, find pattern file - one command).

Comment: I sometimes use netstat -b with grep. `netstat -abon | grep ":33" -A 1`(the process name comes in square brackets one line after, sometimes two lines after so -A 2. One may forget and do grep -C 2 just for more info.  Or to a file (netstat -abon >a) then grep, if I need to grep more than once(as the -b slows it down).    As for useful switches, You can do netstat -aonp tcp or even `netstat -paon tcp`  When you filter to find then  there is less need for -p tcp.   So `netstat -aon | find ":1234"` (for a port)  or | find "1234" for a PID.

Answer (score 5):

Since you are talking about windows, you can use "[netstat -b](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_7-networking/how-to-use-netstat-b-command-to-see-which-process/3b770408-71fa-4cc0-a077-7f97ff249847)" to see which executable is using that port.

Alternatively, Sysinternal's [TCPVIew](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437) does the same, but in a much better and cleaner way.

Comment: He is using `-b` already; it's in `-ab`. Also, the contraction of "you are" is "you're".

Answer (score 1):

http://www.iana.org/assignments/port-numbers
lists this port as: 
winrm           47001/tcp   Windows Remote Management Service
                          Ryan Mack rmack&microsoft.com 29 April 2009

Now that doesn't *prove* that's what using it on your computer, but it's a pretty good guess.

Comment: I saw that as well, but I would like to be sure. If it is a windows service why can't netstat get the ownership info?

Comment: @JayWhite I guess `-b` looks for a path, which the `System` service doesn't have.