# How to delete binded port from cmd in Windows 7?

Tags: windows, command-line, tcp, bind

How to delete binded port in Windows 7 from cmd? I'm developing client server application which running on the port 3434 and also is binded on port 0.0.0.0. When I type in cmd netstat -an, I get this output:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3434           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
```

I can't get ride of them cause don't know the name of port. This 
[link](http://support.Microsoft.com/KB/947709) didn't help me, so can you?

Comment: What, exactly, are you trying to get rid of?  You've run a server application to listen on a TCP port, and `netstat` has told you that you have an application listening on a TCP port.  What's the thing that you are trying to delete, precisely?

Comment: Precisely, delete listening port.

Comment: Your providing the same three word non-explanation a second time doesn't clarify things.  [What are you trying to do?  What has the computer done?  And why do you think that that's in error?](http://homepage.ntlworld.com./jonathan.deboynepollard/FGA/problem-report-standard-litany.html)

Comment: Let's say that you want to close telnet server on 23 port, you will close telnet server or type something like: netsh advfirewall firewall delete rule name="telnsrv.exe" port=23 ... OK! Now think that you don't know the name of telent ("telnsrv.exe"), you just know the port on which some crashed program was run (TCP 127.0.0.1 Thiscomputer:0 LISTENING [system]). How that to put those port in function? How to free those port? (that you can run again program on same port)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

TCP Ports cannot be deleted, you must close the program that has bound itself to that port.

To find out what program is bound to a port use `netstat -ab`

```
 TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        Thiscomputer:0             LISTENING
 [AppleMobileDeviceService.exe]
```

See [How to find exe listening on port?](https://superuser.com/q/246214/52492)

> Try netstat with -o, it shows PID. and then use tasklist to see PID and process name. task manager also shows PID and process name

```
   TCP    127.0.0.1:27015        bcs:49177              ESTABLISHED     1588  
   [AppleMobileDeviceService.exe]
```

[image: Task Manager context menu]
<sub>Using right-click context menu in Task-Manager</sub>

Comment: How to delete this, don't have any .exe: TCP    0.0.0.0:3434           nova:0                 LISTENING
 [System]

Comment: yes thnx for labor, ... but program has run and it was closed, and now when I'm searching for process or name of program don't see anything ... I will trust restart and than try again ...

Comment: @IvanPericic: See updated answer (and related Q)

Comment: I try to restart but same thing, ... still I can't see the name of program just [System] and when trying to end process on him nothing happen .... Probably because my test application has crashed and port that has binded still stayed open.

Comment: OK ... just to say I try to restart one more time and restart explorer with: cmd /c taskkill /f /im explorer.exe & start explorer.exe ... and those probably refresh some configuration, and now when put: netstat -an in cmd doesn't see 3434 port anymore... thxn again

Answer (score 1):

To kill process on windows
run below command to find port and pid

```
netstat -ano
```

to kill a process

```
taskkill /F /PID 1448
```

Answer (score 0):

you can find `process-id` using your `port` number.

`netstat -ano | findstr :<PORT_NUMBER>`

like

`netstat -ano | findstr :9090`

```
TCP    0.0.0.0:9090           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       11332
TCP    [::]:9090              [::]:0                 LISTENING       11332
```

and then close the running process

`taskkill -pid 11332 /f`