# What is using port 80?

Tags: windows, iis

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to find exe listening on port?](https://superuser.com/questions/246214/how-to-find-exe-listening-on-port)

I have 2 web sites that are both configured to run on port 80 but both are stopped. If I start either one, I get the error

> Cannot access the file because it is in use by another process

If I change the port of either web site to 81, they both will run, provided that I only start one of the two.

The question is, since I only see one running web site on port 80, how can I determine what is running on port 80?

Comment: Duplicate of [How to find exe listening on port?](http://superuser.com/questions/246214/how-to-find-exe-listening-on-port) and potentially related to [Why is System Process Listening on Port 80](http://superuser.com/questions/43307/whys-is-system-process-listening-on-port-80).

Comment: I just found that **Skype** listens on port 80. You have to disable this in Tools > Options > Advanced Settings > Connection > "Use port 80 and 443 as alternatives for incoming connections". Craziness.

Answer (score 4):

The command `netstat -ano` will list the PID (process ID) of the process that is listening on each TCP port.  For example on my system PID 4 is listening on TCP port 80.  Using Task Manager shows that process 4 is `system`.

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State           PID
  TCP    0.0.0.0:80             0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1016
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1025           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       712 
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1026           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       1228
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1027           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       756
```

Comment: `-b` will also show the process name :)

Comment: Ah, thank you!  I didn't know that!

Answer (score 1):

You didn't give the version of Windows you're running, but if you're running Windows Server 2008 / Vista or later, Windows comes with a built-in tool (for Administrators only) called `Resource Monitor`.

I could swear this has been asked/discussed before on SU...

[Here](http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/closer-windows-resource-monitor/) is a guide / walk through of the various features of Resource Monitor, one of which is under Network -> Listening Ports. You should be able to find the culprit there.

Resource Monitor is:

- Easily accessible through Task Manager on Windows Vista / Server 2008 or later.
- Graphically oriented and user-friendly.
- Built into the operating system.
- More generally useful than a program that *only* deals with network connections, since it tells you about memory, CPU, and disk also.

Answer (score 1):

The fastest and easiest way to find out is to run [CurrPorts](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/cports.html) or [TCPView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx) and look for port 80 (or *HTTP* if resolving is on). You can also find out about other open ports.

They both give you an easy-to-use GUI to monitor and manage the network connections. For example, you can sort and filter them, and simply right-click and select *Close* to close a connection.

However, if you are getting an accessed denied error on the *file*, then I don’t think that the port being used is the problem (unless the program is simply using a generic error message and means access is denied on the *port*). In case the file is locked (not even with read-sharing), then use a program like [Unlocker](http://www.emptyloop.com/unlocker/) to find out what is locking the web-server’s executable file.