# How to know who is listening to port 80 on Windows in multihomed case?

Tags: windows, networking

How to know who is listening to port 80 on Windows?

Don't suggest to use

```
netstat -aon | findstr :80
```

because it is reporting PID of `NT Kernel & System` which is useless information.

I need to know exact name of component in order to control it.

Comment: Well, if `http.sys` is used, you probably have no chance to find out.

Comment: What is `http.sys`? It is a part of IIS?

Comment: `http.sys` is the Windows Kernel Mode HTTP Engine. It can be used by many programs at the same time, with each listening for requests to a "subdirectory". For .NET, there's the [HttpListener](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httplistener%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) class. IIS also uses `http.sys`.

Comment: … and http://superuser.com/questions/465529/ and http://superuser.com/questions/43307/ .

Answer (score 13):

Well, let's make it an answer.

What you're seeing is most likely the result of a program using `http.sys` the Windows Kernel Mode HTTP Engine introduced in Windows Server 2003 (and XP?). It allows developers to circumvent the limitation that a listening port can only be served by one program at a time. With `http.sys`, a program registers a namespace, e.g. `http://192.168.1.2:80/abc`. The program now receives all requests beginning with the registered namespace. At the same time, another program could listen at `http://192.168.1.2:80/xyz`.

Another side-effect is that even "non-root" programs can listen on port 80, provided that a one-time setup has been completed.

Naturally, Microsoft didn't develop this because it's all fun and games. Internet Information Services (IIS) uses `http.sys` for listening. So this is a likely candidate in your case.

If no program has currently registered namespaces, `http.sys` stops listening.

`netsh http show servicestate` should be able to enumerate all active namespaces.

Comment: Is it possible to list registerings in `http.sys`?

Comment: I've updated the answer to include a command that seems to accomplish this.

Comment: The command above shows process id, so you can find out which exe is listening.

Comment: You mention the example of `http://192.168.1.2:80/helloworld` for program A vs `http://192.168.1.200:80/helloworld` for B, where the IP address (not the path) is different between program A and B. Is this the intended difference, rather than `/helloworld` vs `/somethingelse`?

Comment: @MicroVirus You’re right, I updated the example. Of course, `http.sys` does both: The host and port are also part of the registration.

Answer (score 2):

You *can* try [TcpView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897437.aspx), but if it's in fact in the kernel (as in - a socket opened by a driver), then there's really no way of telling what exactly controls the socket. That's even if you use something like [ProcMon](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896645.aspx) to do the boot tracing and capture the exact moment of a socket getting bound to tcp/80. What you need is a variation of ProcMon that would also capture a stack trace for each event and I haven't seen a tool like this.

But try TcpView first. Chances are that it's actually a user-space service that you are after and not a kernel component.

Comment: `TcpView` shows a very long list with some IPs represented in IPv6 format. No any way to catch specific one.