# Disabling port 80 on Windows Vista

Tags: port, glassfish

I need my Glassfish application server to use port 80 but it complains that it is already being used. I disabled IIS but port 80 was still in use. When I run some netstats, it shows that port 80 is used by "System and Network". I'm not sure why this is. Clearly, shutting down IIS isn't good enough. How can I get port 80 freed up so that I can use it for my Glassfish server?

Comment: Related: http://superuser.com/questions/726963/how-to-know-who-is-listening-to-port-80-on-windows-in-multihomed-case

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to stop http from cmd:

```
net stop http
```

If it doesn't help:

```
netstat -bano
```

This will show you which program exactly uses port 80.