# Why windows listening to port 3000?

Tags: windows, networking, port

by using `netstat -n -o -a` i see that process id 4 listening to that port.

TCP    0.0.0.0:3000           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING       4

By using task manager i found that process id 4 is NT Kernel & System

[image]

hence 
Since i need that port for other service, i am wondering, why the kernel needs to hold that port?

can i release it?

how can i find the specific feature that use that port?

Comment: Check [my answer](https://superuser.com/a/726975/219095) on a related question. It *might* help.

Comment: @DanielB - Perfect! i also voted up the answer there. 
Should i remove that question from here?