# Why does Intel Graphic Command Center leave a web endpoint listening at port 9001 on localhost?

Tags: process, http, intel-graphics

I found out my system process (PID 4) was the one listening on 9001 (both v4 and v6).

Telnet to it, `::1:9001` and enter a char and press <kbd>enter</kbd> I see this:

```
HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request
  Content-Type: text/html; charset=us-ascii
  Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
  Date: Sat, 02 May 2020 21:47:28 GMT
  Connection: close
  Content-Length: 326
  Bad Request
```

It's waiting for a web request…

I found out from this other question:[Port 9001 used by Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0](https://superuser.com/questions/1540248/port-9001-used-by-microsoft-httpapi-2-0)

To run `netsh http show servicestate`

```
Server session ID: FF00000020000001
    Version: 2.0
    State: Active
    Properties:
        Max bandwidth: 4294967295
        Timeouts:
            Entity body timeout (secs): 120
            Drain entity body timeout (secs): 120
            Request queue timeout (secs): 120
            Idle connection timeout (secs): 120
            Header wait timeout (secs): 120
            Minimum send rate (bytes/sec): 150
    URL groups:
    URL group ID: FE00000040000001
        State: Active
        Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
        Properties:
            Max bandwidth: inherited
            Max connections: inherited
            Timeouts:
                Timeout values inherited
            Number of registered URLs: 1
            Registered URLs:
                    HTTP://+:9001/IGCC/SERVICE/
```

Then I see this:

```
Request queues:
    Request queue name: Request queue is unnamed.
        Version: 2.0
        State: Active
        Request queue 503 verbosity level: Basic
        Max requests: 1000
        Number of active processes attached: 1
        Process IDs:
            4741
```

And underneath "Request queues" I found two PIDs. One PID, `4741`, is `OneApp.IGCC.WinService.exe` which is Intel Graphics Command Centre.

What does the Intel Graphics Command Centre need a listening http port for? On my local network I can access the endpoint with `xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:9001` so it seems like a vulenerability for sure.

Is it better to remove certain Intel software?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a form of [Inter-Process Communication](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inter-process_communication), using the network as an Intermediary.

Processes are not able to communicate with each other, without some form of shared interface, and Intel choose to implement a web-based service which allows client software to communicate with a windows service.

Since the advent of UAC and limited user access, MS has recommended that software developers implement windows Services to perform privileged tasks, and to use user-space applications as clients who communicate their wishes to the service. This allows the user to perform well-controlled privileged tasks without the need for administrative access.

In this case, configuring or updating a drivers behavior is an activity that requires admin, so the client just asks the windows service to perform those tasks.

One other note: since the port is bound to 127.x.y.z, it cannot be accessed by any other station. it is limited to the localhost, so local-only ports are not a big security concern from a network perspective, though malicious software on your system might be able to access the service, if Intel didn't do a good job with authentication. like all software, you have to trust the people who wrote it.